# What does the denominator in the tourism tooltip mean?

Tags: simcity-2013

The gambling or culture adviser will show you how many tourists visited your city today and yesterday. If you mouse over the number of tourists, you see a tooltip with a breakdown by wealth level

2,000 / 10,000 low wealth
3,000 / 12,000 medium wealth
80 / 80 high wealth

**What does the number in the denominator mean?** The numerator appears to be the number of tourists of that wealth level who visited the city.

Comment: Shot in the dark guess would be that it might be the total of possible tourists that your city could accommodate of that wealth level. My assumption would be that if you maxed out your tourism, your numerators would match your denominators.

Answer (score 1):

skovacs1, Is actually right on the money.

[image]

As you can see in this example:

**Low Wealth Tourist:** 242/244

**Medium Wealth Tourist:** 15,480/15,491

**High Wealth Tourist:** 77,340/91,520

This city is built specifically around accommodating High Wealth Tourist. The numerator shows how many Tourist I currently have. The denominator shows my current capacity it can currently accommodate.

It should be noted that this number can change at any time even if you don't build anything. Because the hotels (commercial) in your city can keep expanding (growing) to accommodate more and more tourist. I'm not referring to the hotel or suite you build at a casio.